# How to use IF() and ELSE () statements in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I want to DELETE data OR UPDATE data in MYSQL. such that if column **message_deleted_by** is found in a string **IN()** then the query should delete rows where the **WHERE** clause(filtering) is true ELSE the query should update **message_table** column **message_deleted_by** with some data ....ALL IN THE SAME QUERY

if this can be achieved please help.
I'v  tried and tried but it output errors.

```
$token  =   mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc_conn,encode64(getsecreteToken($_POST["token"])));
    $mid    =   mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc_conn,$_POST["mid"]);
    $rid    =   mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc_conn,$_POST["rid"]);
    $sid    =   mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc_conn,$_POST["sid"]);
    $group  =   implode(",",array($rid,$sid));

    $IsLoggIn   = '2';

    $SQL    =   "
                IF(
                SELECT  message_deleted_by AS mdb FROM $message_tatable
                WHERE (
                        m.sender_id='$IsLoggIn' AND m.recipient_id='$rid'
                        ) AND 
                        m.token='$token'  AND m.id='$mid'

                ) mdb  IN($group) THEN

                DELETE  m,mf 
                    FROM $message_tatable m 
                        LEFT JOIN $message_files_tb mf  ON 
                        m.token=mf.token 


                        WHERE (
                        m.sender_id='$IsLoggIn' AND m.recipient_id='$rid'
                        ) AND 
                        m.token='$token'  AND m.id='$mid';

                ELSE
                    UPDATE $message_tatable SET message_deleted_by='$IsLoggIn'
                    WHERE (
                            m.sender_id='$IsLoggIn' AND m.recipient_id='$rid'
                            ) AND 
                            m.token='$token'  AND m.id='$mid';

                END IF;
                    ";

    //QUERY database
    $query  =   mysqli_query($dbc_conn,$SQL);
    die(mysqli_error($dbc_conn));
```

Comment: `DELETE` and `UPDATE` can not be combined. You could write the logic in a stored procedure. But i would just run two queries.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
UPDATE $message_tatable m 
 LEFT JOIN $message_files_tb mf
 ON  m.token=mf.token 
 SET  m=NULL,
  mf=NULL
WHERE m OR mf=SELECT message_deleted_by FROM $message_tatable IN($group)
AND  m.sender_id='$IsLoggIn' AND m.recipient_id='$rid'
AND  m.token='$token'  AND m.id='$mid'
```

Comment: it give the following error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT message_deleted_by FROM messages IN(18,2) AND m.sender_id='2' AND m.rec' at line 6